# Mercurial: How I can use external tool for diff?

Tags: comparison, mercurial, diff

I want to use kdiff3 as a tool for comparing different versions of a repository.
Is there a way how one can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer and want to let it here in order not to forget:

Add to ~/.hgrc file the following sections:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =
```

and then type:

```
hg kdiff3
```